# Load property from credhub and use in PCF manifest

Tags: spring-boot, pcf

I have a PCF manifest file (in spring boot project) where I have added the jasypt encryptor password. I need to move this password to PCF credhub and load the password from there. Is there any posibility of loading the property added in the PCF credhub and read it in the manifest file?

```
---
applications:
  - name: (artifact_id)
    routes:
      - route: (artifact_id)-(space).test.com
    memory: 1GB
    instances: 1
    env:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: dev
      JAVA_OPTS: '-Djasypt.encryptor.password=test@123'
```